# Does the Overleaf community edition have git?

Tags: overleaf

Recently, I installed Overleaf Community edition to Docker, and had started using it. Like the Overleaf online, can I push and/or commit to my git repo?

Comment: Crosspost: https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/hi9xct/overleaf_community_edition_git_integration/

Answer (score 3):

According to this,

https://www.overleaf.com/for/enterprises/features

git support is not included in Overleaf Community.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was useful

Comment: My pleasure. If my answer was helpful, please consider marking your question as answered by checking my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a repo related to this topic:
https://github.com/overleaf/writelatex-git-bridge

But a tutorial is expected